# LaTeX Error: File `Tikztopdf.sty' not found

Tags: tikz-pgf, eps

suddenly I'm no longer able to compile my Ti*k*Z to pdf. The error message says:

> ! LaTeX Error: File `Tikztopdf.sty' not
>   found.

It seems to be a problem of

```
\usepackage{Tikztopdf}
```

As soon as I uncomment it, the error message occur. Has someone an idea what to do? I use TeXMaker. I need an `.eps` output.

This is my sample code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 
\usepackage{pdfpages}
%\usepackage{Tikztopdf}
%-----------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\input{sample_tikz.tex}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

As `sample_tikz.tex` I used this code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=4.521in,
height=3.566in,
at={(0.758in,0.481in)},
scale only axis,
xmin=-4,
xmax=4,
ymin=-1,
ymax=1,
axis background/.style={fill=white},
\addplot [color=blue]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
-3.5    -1\\
3.5 1\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Where did you find that package name?

Comment: There is `tikztopdf`, but it is a shell script https://github.com/ondrik/tikztopdf

Comment: It's long ago when I installed the package, so I don't know where I got it from, sorry. And to be honest, I really don't know what the shell script does. The main problem ist, that there is no longer an .eps-file as output.

Comment: Alright, I found a back-up that works. Nevertheless, thanks for helping.